# dagger2 constructor injection how to provide dependency without module

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-mvp

I've read that constructor injections don't require a module.
So I have this questions.

1. If I have this constructor injection:

   ```
   private Model realmModel;

   @Inject
   public MainActivityPresenter(Model realmModel) {
       this.realmModel = realmModel;
   }
   ```

and this component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {


    Model realmModel();
    void inject(MainActivity activity);


}
```

if in my MainActivity I do it:

```
((MyApp)getApplication()).createAppComponent().inject(this);
```

how could I pass the `realmModel` parameter to the presenter constructor injection?

**EDIT:** this is the model:

```
 Presenter presenter;

 @Inject
 public RealmModel(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You have a cyclic dependency here and you should try to get rid of it. Your model depends on the presenter and the presenter depends on the model. Hence you will not be able to constructor inject either, since neither can be created without the other being created first. Does your model really need to keep a reference to the presenter?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak not sure, I could make a callback to handle the results to the presenter, but without it this works?

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to solve this problem

1) Give a module which does the provide of the Relam Model

```
 @Provides
 @Singleton
 public Model providesRealmModel() {
     return new Model();
 }
```

2) Make your RelamModel class also constructor injected

```
class Model {
   @Inject
   public Model() {}
}
```

The Trick in construction injection is all its dependencies should also be constuctor injeceted then it would work fine.
(From experience your model would need application context. look at the 3 option for ways to implement external Dependencies

3) Provide Model as external dependency.

```
 @Module
 public class ModelModule {
    private Model relamModel;
    public ModelModule(Model relamModel) {
       this.relamModel = relamModel
    }
 }

@Component(module={ModelModule.class}) 
public interface ApplicationComponent {
}
```

Take a look at the series of videos from twisted eqautions these were my first video tutorial on dagger2. I found it really helpful. Hope it helps you too
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qwk7ESmaCq0

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. use a module with a provide method
2. annotate the constructor of `Model` with `@Inject`, doing that when you pass `realmModel` in the presenter contructor, the model
   constructor will be called.

I prefer to use modules, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: so now you need to provide a Presenter.. same steps as with Model

Comment: Presenter is the interface that MainActivityPresenter implements..it's possible to do it?

Comment: so, your mainActivityPresenter has a model, that has a presenter.. mm sounds like you need to work on the design of that..

Comment: the model has the reference to the presenter to give back data...otherwise how presenter could be update the view?

Comment: you can use an interface, or even an event bus.. I recommend using an interface, take a loot at this: https://github.com/matoelorriaga/pokemon. Check the view-presenter-interactor (interactor is what you call model)

Comment: the presenter should implement an interface called inside the "model"

Comment: so it's the Interactor what do you mean?